# Facebook like button (IFRAME) not working

Tags: facebook-like

I have successfully installed the facebook like button in iframe, but it seems like the "Likes" count is incorrect. I have tried liking a post from several accounts, and it always appear as only 1 like.

Any idea how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

I had a some "bug" with facebook like button.
First check yourt metas, and your og: properties. Put your url into a like button generator (http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/) and try to like your page. If the count is 
Please try to change the like url to the facebook page, what is generator for your page to administer it. It was my solution to fix it.